# Preferred way to handle Non-Form-Submitting AjaxEvents in Wicket-Tester

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, wicket-tester

assuming I have the following code in wicket

```
TextField foo = ...;
TextField bar = ...;
bar.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("change") {

        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            // do something
        }

    });
```

let's further assume foo and bar are members of a form "dummyForm" wich has a CompoundPropertyModel as Model. The initial value of the "foo"-field is "Max"

Now I write a simple test with Wicket-Tester:

```
formtester.setValue("foo", "Petra");
wickettester.executeBehavior(...); // execute behaviour on field bar
wickettester.getRequest().getPostParameters();
wickettester.getComponentFromLastRenderedPage("foo").getDefaultModelObjectAsString();
```

When I execute this test the first line puts a post-parameter ("foo", "Petra") in the mock-request. Since the behaviour in the second statment is not a formsubmit-behaviour the CompoundPropertyModel gets not updated. So in line 4 the model-value of foo is still "Max" and not "Petra". I've noticed that the post-parameters got cleared after processing the behaviour, so also line three of my test offers me a empty list of parameters.

So now my question: What's the preferred way to "safe" request-parameter between non-form-submiting requests?

Thanks a lot for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will have to transfer them yourself.
They are available in `#getLastRequest()` instead of `#getRequest()`.

Comment: I thought that this will be our solution. Anyway we will have to think about your testing-scope in the project. We had the idea that everything that we do with wicket-tester will more or less simulate our actions that we would do on the gui. We will spend some time to think about that goal. Thanks for your answer anyway